# Optimal Strategy for Dice-10000 (Dice Game)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory

There exists a dice game known as [Dice-10000](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eflip/games/10000.html), with alternative names such as Dix Mille or 6-Dice

The rules are simple, with each player taking turns rolling dice in order to achieve certain combinations to score points to reach the titular 10,000 points.

Exact combinations can vary greatly, but here is an example ruleset:
[scoring table found on site linked earlier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW2lT.png)

With each successive roll, dice are taken away until a roll is achieved which fail to score anything, in which case all points are lost for the temporary round, and play passes to the next player.

A player may choose to stop rolling dice at any time and add their temporary points to their point total towards 10000.

What would be a method of determining the optimal strategy for Dice-10000?
Moreover, what would be the optimal strategy for Dice-10000?

Comment: https://cupola.gettysburg.edu/csfac/38/

Comment: I have played this game maybe 10000 times :-) and then you develop a bit of a feeling, but it is highly complicated as the link of @EricTowers shows. There is no general best strategy. If you roll for instance a  1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6 it depends if you are leading (then you should play a bit more defensively and take out only the 1) or if your opponent is already at 9000 and then you should take higher risks. Of course there are basic strategies, e.g. if you roll a 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 you should not retain the 5 in order to increase your chances at the next round to get more Ones,

Comment: but in many situations you would need extensive computer simulations to establish the best strategy. It would be interesting to see the full paper of this link cupola.gettysburg.edu/csfac/38 but I can only see the abstract. Maybe you contact the authors and ask for the full paper. If you get hold of it, please let us know, I'd like to read it.

Comment: @RüdiJehn I think the full paper is here: http://cs.gettysburg.edu/~tneller/papers/acg2017.pdf